# Magento: How to call phtml file after registration and redirect to the dashboard page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, registration

I am new to magento,using 1.9.2.4. I have the module of OTP verification and it's working fine. Whenever login, it redirects to dashboard page and ask to  enter verification code.The code in dashboard.phtml is like,

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('test/numberverify.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

so it was asked in dashboard.pthml, but I want to keep this code after register, then this page will appear and then verify after it will redirect to dashboard.phtml. Which files I need to change and how to do this?

numberverify.phtml

```
                 <?php 

             $isuserVerified =     Mage::helper('test/Data')->isUserVerified(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId());
          if($isuserVerified == 'false'): ?>
        <div class="verify_mobile">
         <?php /*?><div class="notverify_yet">
      <?php echo $this->__('*Please verify your mobile with OTP code.'); ?>
```

```
            <label class="verify">
    <?php echo $this->__("Please Enter verification codes"); ?>
</label>
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Enter verification code" class="verify" />
<input type="button"  id="verify_mobile" value="Verify Mobile" class="button verify" />
<?php if(Mage::helper('test/Data')->canResendOTP())
    { ?>
<a href="#" id="resend_mobile_code" class="verify resendcode">Resend Code</a>
<?php } ?>
```

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

    jQuery('#verify_mobile').click(function(e) {
        var code = jQuery("#code").val();
        if(code !== ""){
            jQuery.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                url:'<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'test/index/checkMobileVerificationCode' ?>',
                data:{code:code}, 
                success: function(data) {

                    if(data !== "false"){
                        jQuery(".verify_mobile").css('display','none');
                        showMessage('Thanks for Verification', "success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      showMessage('Please Enter Valid Code!', "error"); 
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error occured');
                }
            });
        }
    }); 

    jQuery('#resend_mobile_code').click(function(e) {
        var code = jQuery("#code").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:'<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'test/index/resendMobileCode' ?>',
            success: function(data) {

                showMessage(data, "success");
            },
            error: function() {
                showMessage('Something went wrong', "error");
            }
        });
    }); 

    function showMessage(txt, type) {
        var html = '<ul class="messages"><li class="'+type+'-msg"><ul><li><span>' + txt + '</span></li></ul></li></ul>';
        jQuery('ul.messages').remove();
        jQuery('.page-title').after(html);
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PM

Go TO This File:
app/design/frontend/customtheme/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

Copy code from  tag close or after close tag.

```
 echo this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('test/numberverify.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Note: Customtheme name will be your theme.

Comment: iam using rwd theme path:app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/test/customer/form/register.phtml

Comment: Go TO This File: app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

Comment: iam using custom code in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/test/customer/‌​form/register.phtml ,i want after click on register numberverify.phtml  page will call

Comment: ok do you want  after  register button click customers will redirect to Otp page?

Comment: yes after register button click customers will redirect to numberverify.phtml and then verify otp it will go to home page or myaccount page @Paarth

Comment: Need to change redirect code in

class Mage_Customer_AccountController

Comment: can you give me the answer for this

Comment: Give me time for this

Comment: make cms -> page name verification & send me url for this page. & i will send you code.

Comment: sure,but i want answer it kills my time @Paarth

Comment: iam doing in my local machine, i updated numberverify.phtml code@Paarth

Comment: update the answer please

Comment: Step 1) Create Cms ->  Page  url key (numberverify)
place this in content: 
<pre>
{{block type="core/template"  name="numberverify" as="numberverify"    template="test/numberverify.phtml"}}
</pre>

Step2)  Go to this controller: Mage_Customer_AccountController
update method: 
protected function _successProcessRegistration with below code 

$url=Mage::getUrl('numberverify');
$this->_redirectSuccess($url);

Comment: ok after that...

Comment: you can do it. it is working i have test. when working you can do overwrite controller is best approach.

Comment: its redirects to that page but functionality not working

Comment: Func you better know how its work my job was to redirect

Comment: js  in that page not loading while adding cms page